# Firestore extension for image resizing caught in infinite loop

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-extensions

*Just want to preface this with, I know the functionality is new, only let out into the wild a week ago! Definitely will be patient with it.*

I've just set the Resize Image extension up and the test run (just uploading an image) is causing an infinite loop of uploads and deletes (and error messages), where the newly resized images appear to be attempting to create new images, or something similar. My input for `Cloud Storage path for resized images` is `images` and this is leading to this error:

`Deleting temporary resized file: 'images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/images/_200x200'`

I'm currently seeing an issue where a single image is causing the function to run until it hits:

```
Error when resizing image { Error: Backend Error
   ...
  code: 503,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'backendError',
       message: 'Backend Error' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Backend Error' }
```

Any ideas for a solution to this? I uninstalled the extension to stop the infinite loop but not sure how to make the extension run smoothly.

The only steps I've taken so far were the setup guide of accepting a few things and changing the path to `images`.

Where's the best place to report this? Happy to delete this on SO if it's not the right place.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug on the firebase extension.

It's already logged here:[github](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/7)

It occurs when your file name does not have an extension like .jpg or .png. As a work around, you might want to rename any files uploaded to the storage bucket to have an extension